# Unable to get past bootloader (either GRUB or Windows Bootloader)

Tags: linux, windows, memory, uefi, bootloader

I recently did some hardware upgrades to my computer. The new specs are:

```
CPU: Ryzen 5 1600
Mainboard: MSI B350 MATE
RAM: G.Skill Ripjaw V Series - 3200 MHz DDR4 - 16 GB (2 x 8 GB)
Video Card: ASUS GeForce GTX 1070 8GB ROG STRIX OC Edition
```

After the upgrades, the computer was working fine for several days. I decided to install Linux Mint onto an SSD that I wasn't using for anything else. After installing it from the Linux live USB without any issues, I rebooted and went to change the boot order so that GRUB would start.

While I was changing the boot order, I saw that my RAM was only running at 2133 MHz, so following suggestions I found online, I enabled A-XMP. As soon as I applied the changes, my computer lost power, and was unable to start.

I removed the battery from the mainboard, and disconnected the computer from power for a couple minutes. After putting the battery back in, I rebooted the computer, and as expected the BIOS default settings had been restored. Unfortunately, the computer was not able to boot after this.

If I boot from my SSD (which has GRUB on it), there is a blinking underscore that goes down 4 lines, then blinks endlessly. If I boot from my hard drive with Windows 10 on it, the characters shown in the pictures below appear on screen, and nothing else happens.
[image]

After this, I ran 3 passes of memtest86, because the screen with the strange characters on it seemed to suggest memory issues to me, but there were no errors detected.

I was able to boot the computer to a Windows recovery USB I had, but upon starting the startup repairs, it crashed, and the computer rebooted.

I was able to boot the computer back to the Linux live USB. I used `badblocks` to check each hard drive and the ssd, but no errors were found. I also ran `memtester` to check the RAM again, but no errors were found.

I tried changing which slots the memory was in, as well as only using one stick, but every configuration seemed to caused it to fail to start. The screen would turn on, but remain black.

This doesn't seem like a hardware problem to me. Maybe there is a problem with the BIOS settings. Does anybody have any advice for how I should proceed?

EDIT 1: I forgot to mention that on every boot up, even when everything was working fine, the CPU, DRAM, and VGA LEDs on the mainboard would light up during boot at different times, then shut off. I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I figure I might as well put any information that could help.

Comment: that's.... VERY... weird. The fact that changing around memory causes it to fail to boot, seems like it could still be a ram issue, especially since that's the setting you changed (weird that memtest wouldn't show it though). Do you have another stick you can test it with? Also, maybe try restoring default settings in bios again just to be sure.

Comment: @Blaine I left the battery out overnight with the power off, then tested it again with the default settings this morning. Same results as before. My next step is going to be to update the BIOS. I do not have any other sticks of RAM to test with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the BIOS, but that didn't seem to fix anything.

I ended up fixing the issue by booting back into the Linux live USB. From the terminal there, I mounted the SSD, and installed GRUB to it. After rebooting, I was able to get to GRUB successfully, and from there I can boot Windows or Linux without problems. I can only assume that GRUB did not install to the correct drive when I did the initial installation of Linux Mint.

Still wasn't able to get my RAM to 3200 MHz, but at least the computer is functioning once more.

Comment: shoot. I'm just now remembering. If it's a corrupt bootloader, there's a command you can run on the windows install disc. something like fixboot and fixmbr